# Breakpoint of number increase in "position()" during foreach

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am increasing a number in an attribute value during "foreach". Since the array of each key with name "product-1", "product-2" etc, has 4 values I need the increase of number to only go from 0 to 3, then repeat from 0 to 3 until end of processed objects.

My original JSON data contains more products. The amount of products is unknown and can differ from time to time. I minimized the JSON data it to better fit in the question.

All code works fine apart from the increase of attributes text value goes from 0 to 6.

**Question:**

How can I adjust the code so the number increase of attribute text value, goes from 0 to 3 and then repeats as part of "foreach".

---

**JSON data:**

```
<data>
{
  "store": {
    "product-1": [0, 3, 2, 1],
    "product-2": [4, 7, 6, 5]
  },
  "other": {
    "Xxx": 42
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <inventory>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </inventory>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Attribute setting -->

  <xsl:attribute-set name="datasheet-result">
    <xsl:attribute name="unitRef">USD</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <!-- Template -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']">

    <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
      <xsl:element name="item:{parent::*/@key}" use-attribute-sets="datasheet-result">
        <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">period{position() - 1}</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1">
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period0">0</item:product-1>
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period1">3</item:product-1>
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period2">2</item:product-1>
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period3">1</item:product-1>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period4">4</item:product-2>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period5">7</item:product-2>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period6">6</item:product-2>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period7">5</item:product-2>
</inventory>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1">
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period0">0</item:product-1>
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period1">3</item:product-1>
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period2">2</item:product-1>
   <item:product-1 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period3">1</item:product-1>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period0">4</item:product-2>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period1">7</item:product-2>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period2">6</item:product-2>
   <item:product-2 unitRef="USD" contextRef="period3">5</item:product-2>
</inventory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siebe has given you an example to use two nested `for-each`s so that `position()` matches your desired result, another option would be to use `xsl:number` instead e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="contextRef">period<xsl:number start-at="0"/></xsl:attribute>` is the shortest example.

As for how `xsl:number` works, in its shortest `<xsl:number/>` basically counts the siblings of the samle "type" as the context node and outputs that number plus one. There are various options to use it in general, see any introduction to XSLT, for instance https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm has a free download of a PDF copy of an introduction to XSLT 2 and 1 ("Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath") and has a section 3 "numbering instructions"/"source tree numbering" in chapter 8 "constructing the result tree".

And of course feel free to browse through the spec section https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#number.

Comment: The suggestion works correct. Could you please add some comments in the answer about what it is in the code suggestion that makes the number increase to restart after number 3?

Answer (score 1):

Use xsl:for-each 2 times like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:element name="item:{parent::*/@key}" use-attribute-sets="datasheet-result">
          <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">period{position() - 1}</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```